# Cache for Java with transactions

Tags: java, caching, transactions

i would like to have a simple cache that supports transactions. With simple I mean that I just want to load all data at startup and no eviction or so is needed. (simple Map would do).

However it should support transactions as that if a change to the database fails, changes made to the cache get rolled back too.

I've heard about JTA but it seems too much for what I need. It would be fine to manually roll back the cache if SQLException is thrown in database transaction.

Are there any options?

If not can someone point me to a good tutorial about JTA? eg. examples and what packages/classes required. Note: I'm creating a framework so it must be able to run standalone without application container.

EDIT:

Forgot 1 very important issue:

Cached objects are immutable! Update means to replace it with a new object that is equal to old one (id based equals method).

EDIT 2:

Wrote JPA instead of JTA...

EDIT 3:

Explanation why simple Map does not work:

I have 2 entity types. I will call them Compound and Element. A compound can consist of multiple elements and each element can appear in multiple compounds.
Elements are managed by my framework. Eg, only compounds can be added directly. The user adds a new compound by specifying its elements. The framework then either selects and exiting element and associates it with the new Compound or create a new Element.

I'm caching all the elements where each element contains a collection of Compound IDs in which the element occurs. Reason for this is that the framework does a special kind of search (eg subgraph isomorphism). For each such search, the whole!!! dataset (all elements) needs to be loaded from database, hence the cache.

Therefore if a new Compound was added or updated, the affected elements in the cache must be updated too.

Solution:

Did what I said in comments:
 - keep ids (=integers) of all changed objects in memory and then only update the changed  ones after database transaction commits.

```
private void updateSearchCache(Collection<String> changedIds,
        Connection connection) {

    synchronized (searchCache) { 
        for (String id : changedIds) {
            Object myObject = getSearchObject(id, connection);
            searchCache.put(id, myObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just put your data into a `Map` *after* transaction is committed to database, can you?

So, your `Map` will contain only the data which is already in database.

Comment: In general true but won't work in my case. The thing is I'm dealing with very heavy objects and application must be able to add many of those at once from a file as example. So I read from the file (thread 1) and insert (thread 2) at same time using a BlockignQueue to limit the number of objects in memory. hence once the transaction commits, I don't know what to insert into the cache. There is more to it, that also hinders this approach.

Comment: @beginner_ Can you save ids of objects which are committed to DB? If yes, you can read them from DB after whole file is processed, but before start of calculations. This will work, of course, only if total size of committed objects can be fit into your app's heap.

Comment: If not, you can save in cache only last N most recently accessed items which are already committed.

Comment: Yeah was thinking about keeping ids of new/changed objects and then change cache after commit. have to think about it. Will edit my question to add more detail what I cache.

Answer (score 0):

[Berkeley DB](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/08/24/sleepy.html) can be used to create [in-memory tables](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/BerkeleyDB/ref/program/ram.html) and has [transactional support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/JAVA/enabletxn.html).

It's a fine choice, if what you want to store are blob->blob mappings, but it is not an object cache.

Comment: How does it compare to like HSQLDB memory-tables? But I think we both agree it's a lot slower than simple Map access. It must be very fast for reads!

Answer (score 0):

Transactional caching is possible with [infinispan](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+transactions). Although it is designed as a clustered cache it can be [easily run on one machine](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Local+mode+cache). The cache-api extends java.util.Map and is easy to use.

Comment: Just saw i wrote JPA instead of JTA in my question. Preferably I would like to avoid it as JPA seems rather heavy for my use case but maybe I'm wrong.